# Getting this error code: " (node:25096) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'channel' of undefined "

Tags: discord.js

Hi I've been trying to get a discord bot to join a voice channel for a while and have been struggling, this is the code i have so far and i get this message when i type "/join" in the general chat of the server. Thanks in advance!

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const client = new Discord.Client();

client.login('my token);

 client.on('message', async message => {
// Voice only works in guilds, if the message does not come from a guild,
// we ignore it
if (!message.guild) return;

if (message.content === '/join') {
  // Only try to join the sender's voice channel if they are in one themselves
  if (message.member.voice.channel) {
    const connection = await message.member.voice.channel.join();
  } else {
    message.reply('You need to join a voice channel first!');
  }
}
});
```

Comment: Replace "message.member.voice.channel" with "message.member.voiceChannel".

Comment: That still doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: You change in 2 places?

Comment: omg i'm braindead, thank you guys soooo much it finally works!!!